# How to customize the fork process?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, gitlab

I would like to execute extra actions after a successful fork .

(e.g. automate the creation of a `CruiseControl.net` project).

Which code should I modify? Where should I start from?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to implement that, according to the source code.

- the first option should be: modify [app_services/projects/fork_service.rb](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/6-7-stable/app/services/projects/fork_service.rb)
- another option could be: implement a project_service (e.g. [model](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/6-7-stable/app/models/project_services/emails_on_push_service.rb), worker), which will be binded to an external (unexisting) API which will manage the complexity of the project creation

(more links when my reputation will be high enough ;-))